# How do I change the frequency of an rf module?

Tags: rf, radio, 433mhz

I recently bought an [AM radio transmitter/receiver](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/RF-Wireless-Transmitter-and-Receiver-Link-Kit-Module-433Mhz-For-Remote-Control-/160871598791?pt=UK_Gadgets&hash=item2574b1cac7) from eBay.

It was only after I bought it, however, that I noticed that the frequency was 315/433 MHz. I live in the UK so only 433 MHz would be legal for my use. At the bottom of the eBay page it says that I can set the frequency. How do I go about doing so. Thanks in advance, I've never used radio communications before.

Comment: The way that is written, I believe the Ebay seller just copied the product description from the actual manufacturer. The way to get a different frequency would be to contact the manufacturer and order parts built with different components that give the frequency you choose.

Comment: Normally I'd look in the datasheet, but I can't find an English one for this (I think it's an Aoke AK-R03A based on that image)

Comment: Since the Ebay seller lists the part as a "433 MHz" module, they have *probably* done just that, and ordered the part configured for 433 MHz. But of course, on Ebay you never really know what you're going to get.

Comment: Aaaah. On the transmitter, there's a crystal that says 315.000 on it. I guess I'm going to have to send this thing back?

Comment: At GBP 1 for the product and GBP 2 for S&H, I'm thinking either you or (if you're lucky) the Ebay guy is going to end up eating the cost of the part you have, and if you're lucky you'll get a new part with a configuration that matches the advertised product description.

Comment: Have used maky of these ASK/OOK 433MHz modules. Yes, they are always produced in those 2 frequency-bands i.e. 315MHz (most common in China), and 433-434MHz (more common elsewhere). Unless this is a high-power / long-range version, for a one-off use and you plan to use it outdoors, you might safely be able to use it anyhow. At that price, it is not fair to expect seller to replace those modules. For higher-volume usage, most east-asian vendors need you to explicitly specify which option(s) you need.

Comment: I'm just a bit annoyed that I'm going to have to wait another two weeks for another one to arrive. Thanks for the help everybody.

Answer (score 1):

To change the transmit frequency you'll have to change the SAW resonator as well as some component values, not really what I'd call practical. The receiver frequency is fairly easy to adjust, turning out the glued in inductor reduces the frequency, I was able to turn mine down to 405MHz by completely turning out the iron screw.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily change the carrier freq. as this simple design uses a Narrowband SAW filter.

Ironically the photo shows the part for a P315 (MHz) part yet says it is advertised as a 433 MHz device, so the photo does not seem to represent the exact part. If you buy another SAW resonator or another package, you may be able to change it.

> ```
> Model Nom. f Insertion Loss   Quality factors     Package
>
>               .       (MHz) (dB)  Q, Unloaded Q 50Ω load  
>
>
>  p315 315.000 ≤ 2.0   ≥12,000     ≥2,000  .      TO-39,F11 TO-39, F11
> ```

They forgot ( I believe) to tell you how to specify the Tx frequency on your order. The Rx is wide band.